# Improving readability of multiple if statements with common pattern

Tags: javascript, readability

I am doing some JavaScript front-end and I have a heavy load of forms, all of which need validation. As of now I am using this structure :

```
function validateForm() {
    let form = document.forms["form-add-consumer"];

    let id = form["input-id"].value;
    let lastName = form["input-last-name"].value;
    let firstName = form["input-first-name"].value;
    ...

    let missing = false;
    if (lastName.trim() === "") {
        document.getElementById("input-last-name-error").className = "error";
        missing = true;
    }
    if (firstName.trim() === "") {
        document.getElementById("input-first-name-error").className = "error";
        missing = true;
    }

    if(missing){
        return false
    } else {
        return buildRequest(id, firstName, lastName, ...);
    }
}
```

As you can see, for large forms the function will quickly grow. The code is a bit redundant for each field:

1. Declare form field
2. Check its value against a boolean condition
3. If boolean failed, display the error label and set the failed boolean to true to not send the request

How could I improve this code without complexyfing it too much (no library if possible) ?

Comment: It seems like you could save yourself a lot of trouble by using HTML form validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks ! It seems a great option. I will not be able to fully use it with the custom form elements and legacy browsers apparently, but it is still a great thing to know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create an object that contians per-field validators, with selectors for respective fields, so that you can perform the nessisary validation in a more concise way like so:

```
function validateForm() {
    let form = document.forms["form-add-consumer"];

    let id = form["input-id"].value;
    let lastName = form["input-last-name"].value;
    let firstName = form["input-first-name"].value;
    ...

    // Construct an object with selectors for the fields as keys, and 
    // per-field validation functions as values like so
    const fieldsToValidate = {
      '#input-id' : value => value.trim() !== '',
      '#input-last-name' : value => value.trim() !== '',
      '#input-first-name' : value => value.trim() !== '',
      ...,
      '#number-field' : value => parseInt(value) > 0, // Different logic for number field
      ...
    }

    const invalidFields = Object.entries(fieldsToValidate)
    .filter(entry => {

        // Extract field selector and validator for this field
        const fieldSelector = entry[0];
        const fieldValueValidator = entry[1];
        const field = form.querySelector(fieldSelector);

        if(!fieldValueValidator(field.value)) {
            // For invalid field, apply the error class
            field.className = 'error'
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    // If invalid field length is greater than zero, this signifies
    // a form state that failed validation
    if(invalidFields.length > 0){
        return false
    } else {
        return buildRequest(id, firstName, lastName, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but It would only work if the only condition is to not be empty. My fault I did not highlight it and the example does not show it, but for some fields I need to check against other conditions (is greater than, is not a certain value, ...)

Comment: @Dranna just made a few updates to answer - does that help you?

Comment: Thanks, I adapted it to select the label error field (by using a selector + '-error') and it works.
I am not sure if it helps in readability but it reduces the amount of variability between validations and the number of lines of code